# How do I loop through an array of ip adresses to get the hostname of each machine in bash?

Tags: bash, backup, rsync

I'm trying to learn to write some simple bash scripts and I want to create a backup script that will use rsync to fetch predetermined directories and sync them to a backup machine. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash


#Specify the hosts
ip=(192.168.1.40 192.168.1.41 192.168.1.42 192.168.1.43)
#currently unused
webdirs=(/etc/nginx/sites-available/ /var/www/ghost)
#Directory to store everything
NAS=/mnt/synology/Torrents/Games/


#Remote-hosts to rsync from
for i in "${ip[@]}"
do
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
NAS2=$HOSTNAME$NAS
  if [ ! -d "$NAS2" ]; then
    echo $NAS2 "does not exist, creating..."
    mkdir -p $NAS2
  else
    echo "inside the else"
    sudo rsync -anvzP -e "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" victor@$i:/etc  $NAS2/
  fi
done;
```

It's not done but I've ran into a problem. I can't figure out how to create new directories for each machine. Right now it's only creating the directory for my web server.

EDIT: I solved it by using ssh and command substitution, all I did was this:

```
HOSTNAME=$(ssh user@$i "hostname")
```

The variable $HOSTNAME will change after each iteration. Exactly what I want.

Comment: Not sure what your issue is.  Is your loop terminating too early?  Try adding `-n` option to `ssh`.

Comment: @codeforester This is the output i get when i add the -n parameter to ssh.

`victor@webserver:~$ ./backup.sh 
    skapar mapp
    rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
    rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
    rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
    rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226)  [Receiver=3.1.1]`

I'm sorry i dont understand how to format code in comments..

This happens 4 times which is equal to the amount of hosts

Comment: You shouldn't use all-caps variable names, like `NAS`, `NAS2`, and `HOSTNAME`. There are a number of all-caps names (including `HOSTNAME`) that have special meanings to the shell and/or other utilities, and reusing them for other things can cause trouble. Thus, it's safest to use lower- or mixed-case variable names to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

is your desired output is something like:

```
$host/mnt/synology/Torrents/Games/
```

where `$host` is the name of each one of these ips: (192.168.1.40 192.168.1.41 192.168.1.42 192.168.1.43) ?

when building the path for `mkdir` you are doing `$(hostname)` but that command's output will be your local machine name; it won't run in each host.

if you want each hosts name you should launch that command through ssh in each IP and retrieve the output.